# php Считать и удалить певую строку файла, не загружая его в память

Tags: php, файлы

Необходимо считать первую строку из файла и удалить ее, не загружая файл в память, т.к. он весит более 20гб. 
Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написал вариант, который работает если строки в файле уникальные, что в моем случае подходит. Но это не совсем правильный ответ. Буду рад, если кто-то даст верный ответ.

```
<?php
$fileName = 'c:\php\test.txt';

$fd = fopen($fileName, 'a+');
$str = fgets($fd);
var_dump($str);

$tm = fopen($tmpname = $fileName.'_temp', 'w+');
while (($line = fgets($fd)) !== false) {
  if($str == $line) continue;
  fwrite($tm, $line);
}
fclose($fd);
fclose($tm);
rename($tmpname, $fileName);
```

Comment: не понял, а зачем здесь вообще какое-то сравнение?

Comment: После объявления $tm добавьте строку `fgets($fd)`. В цикле `if ... ` нужно убрать. Всё

Comment: @Ипатьев чтобы пропустить первую строку

Comment: @ArchDemon так ведь остается первая строка

Comment: ТЫ ЕЁ УЖЕ пропустил

Comment: @Ипатьев нет. Если без if делать, то оно просто копирует файл((

Comment: как он скопирует если ты начинаешь копирование со второй строчки? потому что первую прочитал раньше

Comment: @Ипатьев Копирует с первой строчки. Я проверял, потому и добавил if

Comment: о господи. тот кот который написан здесь, пропускает первую строчку без всяких ифов. Ты вообще в состоянии прочесть код, который сам же написал?

Comment: Я еще раз говорю, что без добавления проверки, он копирует файл полностью, с первой строкой. Я проверял. Потому и добавил эту проверку.